# method for move window

Tags: c#, window, refresh

I want do something like that:
I have form with pictures, when I click on ones, I want to display new window with this picture (it must be only picture, without some toolbox or border). Continuing I want to be able move this window (when I press button on mouse and move mouse, this window must move with my cursor, when I up button window won't move when I move mouse).

I do it like that:
make new window form, remove toolbar, border, add pictureBox, add method on mouseDown, mouseUp and mouseMove. Code for method:

```
    private void FormZdjecie_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
        buttonUp = false;
        previous = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
        buttonUp = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
        if ( !buttonUp ) {

            Point diff = new Point();
            diff.X = e.X - previous.X;
            diff.Y = e.Y - previous.Y;

            this.Location = new Point( this.Location.X + diff.X, this.Location.Y + diff.Y );

            previous = e.Location;
        }
    }
```

I work, but it very slow refresh. How do it to work like windows form (when I move normal windows form it look fine), but my method look badly ;p Any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the WinAPI. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpmovewindow.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981006/problems-with-moving-window it's link for now question